# How does `ld` find secondary dependencies for shared objects?

Tags: ld

I have a situation where we link to some shared library `libfoo.so`, that in turn depends on `libbar.so`. In case we link an executable that depends on `libfoo.so` directly we compile it by giving the flags:

```
-L<location of libbar.so> -lfoo
```

This however picks up a `libbar.so` in the system path instead of the location specified on the command line with the incorrect set of symbols resulting in undefined references. If we change the command to:

```
-L<location of libbar.so> -lfoo -lbar
```

The right `libbar.so` is found by `ld`. Is this to be expected? How can we tell `ld` to find a secondary dependency in some location without explicitly linking to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not specify `-lbar`, the indirect dependent libbar is added implicitly. In this case the compile time linking search mechanism for this library is different (it is then similar how the runtime linker `ld.so` would search the library at runtime). Have a look at the `-rpath-link` option in the `ld` manual. There you can see that searching in `-L` directorys for this case is only done on SunOs systems. The best way to specify a compile time linking search path for indirect dependencies ist to use the `-rpath-link` option, because this has the highest search priority.